# Cannot find libtcod.hpp on Xcode on MacOS Mojave even though it is included?

Tags: libtcod

I'm trying to create my own game through the libtcod library on MacOS. I've installed the library for mac and made sure that all the files are in the folder. When I try to test my code in Xcode, it says that the header file (libtcod.hpp)
cannot be found. I already included all the files in the frameworks and libraries section so it doesn't exactly make sense as to why the code cannot find the header file.

Here's the tutorial I'm following: http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Complete_roguelike_tutorial_using_C%2B%2B_and_libtcod_-_part_1:_setting_up#Installing_the_compiler

Screenshot of the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1NPT.jpg

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Did you definitely complete the step `Then you'll have to copy those files from the libtcod directory to your project directory`. Maybe you could post the directory structure?

Comment: @Deancoakley I did copy all files from libtcod into my include folder and then linked that to XCode, i may have linked the wrong files however not too sure.

Image for Frameworks/Library: https://imgur.com/a/cNla07r
Image of project directory: https://imgur.com/a/iqVEZdz